# Program prints individual lines and not whole file

Tags: python-3.x

This is a homework assignment and i can't seem to figure it out.

"Write a program that asks the user for the name of a file. The program should display only the first five lines of the file's contents. If the file contains less than five lines, it should display the file's entire contents."

Whenever the program reads a file with more then 5 lines it only prints the first 5 lines. However when a file is read with less then 5 lines it should print the whole file but it does not do that. Any help is appreciated.

```
def file_head_display():
    total = 0
    file = str(input('Enter the name of the file'))
    f_open = open (file, 'r')
    line1 = f_open.readline()
    line2 = f_open.readline()
    line3 = f_open.readline()
    line4 = f_open.readline()
    line5 = f_open.readline()



    for line in f_open:
        amount = int(line)
        total += amount

    if total > 5:
        print(line1)
        print(line2)
        print(line3)
        print(line4)
        print(line5)
    else:
        contents = f_open.read()
        print(contents)


file_head_display()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working solution**

```
def file_head_display(limit = 5):
    file = str(input('Enter the name of the file: '))
    f_open = open (file, 'r')

    line_counter = 0        
    for line in f_open:                  # for each line in the text file
        if line_counter < limit:         # if current line is < 5
            print(line, end="")          # then print the line
            line_counter += 1
        else:                            # else, stop looping
            break

file_head_display()
```

**Explanations**

There are several issues about your snippet:

- Each call to `readline` consume one line, so the `for` loop you are using start *after* the 5 first lines.
- The for loop iterate over a line in the file; it isn't a counter of line (so converting to int is a mess)
- Please use loop wisely, do not write 5 times the same thing

Comment: Thank you the code you gave worked. I am still figuring out what the diffrent statements are doing in the code you provided. Thanks!